# Video not playing when creating a video by skipping frames

Tags: python, opencv

I have a video xx.mp4 of size 73.7MB. It has a large number of frames so I want to reduce it by taking only every 5th frame. This is the code I've written (using the answer of Masoud Rahimi [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57139005/how-can-i-extract-frames-from-a-video-at-a-certain-fps))

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('xx.mp4')
length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
print(length)

if (cap.isOpened) == False:
    print('unable to read file')
    
frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
frame_height = int(cap.get(4))

i = 0
frame_skip = 5

out = cv2.VideoWriter('outskipframe.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'), 10, (frame_width, frame_height))
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    if i > frame_skip -1:
        out.write(frame)
        i = 0
        continue
    i+=1    

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The video `outskipframe.mp4` is saved with a size of 911MB but when I try to play it using cv2.VideoCapture, I get an error for the condition `(cap.isOpened()==False)` . I checked the number of frames and it shows 0.

I tried writing the same video without skipping any frames and it works perfectly, copying the exact same file (with fewer fps but an extremely large size of 5.5GB)

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The condition had to be set to while True. I'm still understanding why this is.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('xx.mp4')
length = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
print(length)

if (cap.isOpened) == False:
    print('unable to read file')
    
frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
frame_height = int(cap.get(4))

i = 0
frame_skip = 5

out = cv2.VideoWriter('outskipframe.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'), 10, (frame_width, frame_height))
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    if i > frame_skip -1:
        out.write(frame)
        i = 0
        continue
    i+=1    

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try your code using this VideoWriter line?

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('test.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V'), 10, (width, height));
```

I don't think the fourcc code you have right now is valid for .mp4, at least, it isn't a valid codec for me.

Comment: Thank you! But I already tried this fourcc code without skipping frames and it works fine. So that's not the issue.